How to sync events on different websites in chrome?
I have one website that tracks a users state (if they are working or on break), I have second website doing the exact same thing (tracking users). The two websites report to different entities so the person has to click break/working on both websites (we cannot get rid of one). I want to know what is the easiest way to turn these 2 clicks into one. I want to be able to click 'break' once and it reflects on both websites that I am on break. Please note, I am a 3rd party and I have user/limited access to these websites.
I have been considering building a Chrome extension since the websites are used on Chrome only. I don't any experience building Chrome extensions so please let me know where to start if that's the solution

you can use websockets
basically in your chrome extension listen to one of the events and send a message to the background script, then in the background script send a message to server or handel the event somehow
//content js 
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "state_sync"});

port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  // receive event 
  if (msg.event.name === "MyEvent"){
    const new_state = msg.state
    const eventData = msg.event 
  }
});


window.addEventListner(MyEvent, (event) => {
   // send event 
   port.postMessage({message: {state:event.data}});
})


//background.js
//listen for message from content.js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name === "state_sync");
 /// send message over websocket
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify( msg )); 
}
// receive over websocket
ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    const state = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log('Updated state received:', state);
    // Do something with the updated state
};

there's many libraries that can help, here's one "socket-league-client: Websockets that transfer synced state"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket-league-client
